# Easy c++ question regarding valarray

Tags: c++

Most posts probably ask question as to why something is not working; mine is to ask why something **IS** working...

I thought that the only way to dynamically allocate memory was with the use of `new` or `malloc` in cpp, but this is apparently wrong. The following code both compiles and works, but cannot figure out why!

```
int x; 
cin >> x;
valarray<double> data(x);
// initializing elements and printing the array both work fine....
```

It is driving me crazy. x is not known at compile time, only at run time, and I am not doing:

```
int x;
cin >> x;
valarray<double> *data;
data = new valarray<double> (x);
...
```

As you would to dynamically allocate an array. I apparently have a fundamental flaw of memory allocation.*** Can someone shed light as to why both of these work??**

EDIT: I edited my question to make the actual question I am looking for more clear.

Comment: Does anyone actually use valarray?

Comment: @unapersson: people should, it works well enough for its purpose. I think nobody knows about it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic memory allocation is hidden inside of the constructor of the `valarray` class and still uses `new` or `malloc` in the end.

Instead of `valarray` you could also use a `vector`. Both classes can be resized at runtime.

That the complexity is hidden behind the interface of the classes is an advantage. You don't ever have to remember to call `delete` since the destructor of the class will take care of that even when exceptions are beeing thrown; they are exception safe!

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to get at, thanks. There is still a new or malloc keyword occuring, its just hidden from view.

Comment: @Tommy Which is, arguably, the way it should be. Not having to deal with `new` or `delete` or `malloc` or `free` yourself and instead having the language handle it is good.

Answer (score 0):

`valarray<double> (x)` invokes the constructor and although the object is already allocated (on the stack), you allocate the elements of the array through this constructor. Allocating the elements is done internally in the constructor.

`new valarray<double> (x)` does the same, but it allocates the *object itself* as well, because `new` is used. So the object as well as the array elements will be stored on the heap.

Comment: How is it still being allocated to the stack even though x is unknown? Thats what I am trying to get at; the first code block would not work with standard arrays (you would have to use the second block), so what is special about valarray?

Comment: `valarray<double> data;` allocates the `data` object on the stack. Now the object itself (think of it as a container) is already there. To actually create the elements inside this object you invoke the constructor. Don't confuse this with standard arrays - standard arrays are arrays themselves, not objects that encapsulate arrays.

Comment: So its a container that will point to the heap I am guesssing. The "size of the container" is not known, so it cannot allocate all the memory needed for the elements on the stack, correct?

Comment: I guess `valarray` will never allocate the elements themselves on the stack, it doesn't make sense. Please make a distinction between allocating an object and internal allocation (based on its behaviour) of its properties which the object does through its constructor.

Comment: Thanks! Better understanding now

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
valarray<double> data;
```

is automatically creating a `valarray<double>` object on the stack and is calling the no-argument constructor.

The line

```
data = valarray<double> (x);
```

translates to

```
data.operator=(valarray<double> (x));
```

which calls the valarray constructor that takes an int.  What ends up happening is that another object is automatically created on the stack and is then assigned to the first object.

Note that it would be better to do

```
valarray<double> data(x);
```

so that you only create one object instead of creating two and throwing one away.

---

**Edited to address other OP comments**

`x` is **not** unknown.  The `cin >> x;` line in your program is setting `x`.  So when the `valarray` constructor is called it is being passed an actual value.  At the bottom it's no different than this (though of course since the memory allocation is internal to `valarray` it can make sure to `delete` automatically it when the object goes away):

```
int* makeArray(int size) {
    return new int[size];
}

int main() {
    int s;
    cin >> s;

    int* theArray = makeArray(s);
    // do stuff

    return 0;
}
```